# Avoiding reflection in calling a Java variadic method in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to avoid reflection in calling [IssueInputParameters.addCustomFieldValue()](http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/5.0.1/com/atlassian/jira/issue/IssueInputParameters.html#addCustomFieldValue(java.lang.Long,%20java.lang.String...)) from the JIRA API. However, even when fully type-hinted, Clojure still emits a warning that reflection is in use.

The method signature given in the javadocs is as follows:

```
IssueInputParameters addCustomFieldValue(Long customFieldId, String... values)
```

As such, I'm attempting to call it as so:

```
(fn [^com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueInputParameters i, ^Long l]
  (.addCustomFieldValue i l (into-array String ["foo"])))
```

Actual invocations work, but reflection is always used:

```
Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_PATH:1 - call to addCustomFieldValue can't be resolved.
```

How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hinting the `String[]` explicitly works when done as follows:

```
(fn [^com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueInputParameters i, ^Long l]
  (.addCustomFieldValue i l
    ^"[Ljava.lang.String;" (into-array String ["foo"])))
```